# Determine a fundamental matrix of a vertorial ODE.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I must determine a fundamental matrix of the vectorial ODE

$\dot{x}(t) =  \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 4 \\
3 & 2 
\end{bmatrix} x(t)$.

In what form is a fundamental matrix? Should I just solve the ODE with eigenvalues and eigenvectors to compute the general solution? What is asked from me here?

Comment: Well, presumably you have been given some definition of what the words “fundamental matrix” mean? So the first thing to do would be to recall that definition.

Comment: I was assuming it was a general term, it's probably not.

Comment: It is a standard term. What I meant was that if you want to solve this problem, and you don't know what that term means, the first thing that you obviously need to do is to **look it up** – how else are you going to understand what is asked from you? And if this problem is part of some course that you're taking, the definition should be somewhere in your course materials (the textbook or lecture notes or videos or whatever).

Comment: Otherwise, just search the web. Like this, for example: https://www.google.com/search?q=site:math.stackexchange.com+fundamental+matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fundamental matrix $\Phi(t)$ is a matrix $\Phi:I\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ such that $$\boxed{\Phi'(t)=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 4\\ 3 & 2\end{pmatrix}\Phi(t) \text{ and } \text{det}(\Phi(t))\neq 0, \forall t\in I}$$ For systems of differential equations $x'=Ax$ such that the matrix $A$ is constant (as in your case), then it can be proved that $$\Phi(t)=e^{tA}:=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{t^nA^n}{n!}$$
The problem comes when the matrix $A$ is not diagonalized. In that case it must be first diagonalized and then compute the series. Suppose that $A=P^{-1}DP$, where $D$ is a diagonal matrix, then
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{t^nA^n}{n!}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{t^n(P^{-1}DP)^n}{n!}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{t^nP^{-1}D^nP}{n!}=P^{-1}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{t^nD^n}{n!}P$$ So, by using the definition of the exponential matrix this is the same as saying that $$e^{tA}=P^{-1}e^{tD}P$$ so it is essential for our problem to know how to compute $e^{tD}$ where $D$ is a diagonal matrix. But this is easy since $$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 4\\3 & 2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-\frac{3}{7} & \frac{3}{7}\\ \frac{3}{7} & \frac{4}{7}\end{pmatrix}^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}-2 & 0\\0 & 5\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}-\frac{3}{7} & \frac{3}{7}\\ \frac{3}{7} & \frac{4}{7}\end{pmatrix}$$ and $$e^{tD}:=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{t^nD^n}{n!}=I_2+tD+\frac{t^2D^2}{2!}+\dots=\begin{pmatrix}e^{-2t} & 0\\ 0 & e^{5t}\end{pmatrix}$$
So, $$\Phi(t)=\begin{pmatrix}-\frac{3}{7} & \frac{3}{7}\\ \frac{3}{7} & \frac{4}{7}\end{pmatrix}^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}e^{-2t} & 0\\ 0 & e^{5t}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}-\frac{3}{7} & \frac{3}{7}\\ \frac{3}{7} & \frac{4}{7}\end{pmatrix}$$
to convince yourself that this is indeed a fundamental matrix for the system, try and see if it satisfies the definition of such a matrix.

If you found this answer helpful, please consider to pin it. Thanks!